# How do I get my microphone to work on my chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extensions, microphone, chromebook

I have an acer chromebook and I recently found out that my mic doesn't work on it now. I reset it to default settings and nothing. I'm going to assume that it has something to do with the new update, but I don't know. Is there a way to fix this issue? I've tried googling it, but it is kind of hard to find anything related to acer chromebooks.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to say exactly what the issue could be. I do recommend checking the settings for the microphone and possibly flash. It's possible that it was blocked by Chrome and the reason it's not working. To find the settings navigate to Settings > Advanced Settings > Content Settings and check the permissions.

Comment: There is no content setting under advanced

Answer (score -1):

Dead serious check and make sure your bluetooth setting isn't on. Just turned it off and my microphone is working again!